# VBA Help: Object Required Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

I'm trying to take data from a bunch of word documents and add them to an excel spreadsheet using the below code I found on this site. However, after editing the code to select specific documents via the path, I continue to get "object required" errors when I try to run the code. Could you please explain where I'm going wrong and how to fix it? Sorry I'm fairly new to VBA and I'm pretty lost as a result.

```
    Sub Macro1()
   Dim xl As Object
   Set xl = CreateObject("excel.application")

   xl.Workbooks.Add
   xl.Visible = True

   'Here put your path where you have your documents to read:
   myPath = "C:\Users\arahmani\Desktop\march\"  'End with '\'
   myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.docx")
    
   xlRow = 1
   Do While myFile <> ""
      Documents.Open Filename:=myPath & myFile, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
         ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, PasswordDocument:="", _
         PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, WritePasswordDocument:="", _
         WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""

      xlCol = 0
      Dim t As ListObject
      For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
         For Each Row In t.Rows
            For Each c In r.Range.Cells
               myText = c
               myText = Replace(myText, Chr(13), "")
               myText = Replace(myText, Chr(7), "")
               xlCol = xlCol + 1
               xl.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(xlRow, xlCol) = myText

            Next c
            xlRow = xlRow + 1
            xlCol = 0
         Next Row
      Next t
      ActiveWindow.Close False
  

      myFile = Dir
   Loop

   xl.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So which line is failing? Have you tried using the VBA debugger?

Comment: I have tried using it, but it doesn't specify where the error is occurring. However, I think it might be from t, r, and c ? I tried using Dim r As Range and Dim c As Range but that led to another error, "argument not optional"

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to be sure, but as a starting point

```
Dim t As ListObject
```

Should be

```
Dim t As Table
```

If this is Mac Office, you could well be getting a problem even when you try to do the initial CreateObject.

Comment: I tried using that, but I got a "User type not defined" error signal? Could you please help me fix that?

Comment: @AryaRahmani make sure the Excel object library is referenced, and use `As Excel.ListObject` and `As Word.Table` (i.e. properly qualify the object types with the library they're defined in) - otherwise you'll run into more problems when you start involving `Range` objects (both libraries define a `Range` class, with very different properties and methods)

Answer (score 0):

[Object required (Error 424)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-required-error-424) occurs because:

> References to properties and methods often require an explicit object qualifier.

You are trying to use MS Word document without declaring it. You should create the Word application object first.

```
Set wrd = CreateObject("word.Application")
```

Then use it to open the document.

```
wrd.Documents.Open Filename:=myPath & myFile
```